# mock a static method in jasmine using the useClass statement

Tags: angular, jasmine, static-methods

I think I probably should use a spyObject and I am on the wrong track but is it possible to mock a static function with useClass in Jasmine Angular testing?

The code I am testing is:

```
this.authenticationContext.onClaimsChange().subscribe((claims) => {
    if (!AuthenticationContext.isAzureIdentity(claims))
        return;
....
```

What I have done is:

created a fake class:

```
class FakeAuthenticationContext {
    private fake: { [claim: string]: string | string[] } = {claim:['fake']};

    onClaimsChange(): Observable<{ [claim: string]: string | string[] }>
    {
        console.info('at onClaimsChange');
        return of(this.fake)
    }
    static isAzureIdentity(claims: { [claim: string]: string | string[] }): boolean     {
        console.info('at isAzureIdentity');
        return (true)
    }
}
```

and in the providers for the tests I added:

```
providers: [
  ...
  {provide: AuthenticationContext, useClass: FakeAuthenticationContext}

]
```

But it does not work because the code in the component will look for the static function 'AuthenticationContext.isAzureIdentity' not 'FakeAuthenticationContext.isAzureIdentity'

Is there any other way, apart from using the different approach with the spy object that you can make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do the following:

```
const isAzureIdentitySpy = spyOn(AuthenticationContext, 'isAzureIdentity');

isAzureIdentitySpy.and.returnValue(true);
```

The above will spy on the `AuthenticationContext.isAzureIdentity` and return true.

Comment: I think I did try that but it did not work because it was a static function. Let me check again. I solved it by working around it at the moment, so the mock now creates the right input for the static function to return true. But I am curious how you could fix it by creating some kind of a mock for the static method.

Comment: It's difficult to do because when the test is running, it is using `AuthenticationContext` and not `FakeAuthenticationContext`.

Comment: No it does not work with spy neither, it only works with non static methods. I do not know if it could be possible with a spyObject somehow, but it keeps using the non mocked version. The only way I could find to work around it is: let the other mocked methods create the right outcome that will make your static method adapt to the right path you want to test.